# Conditional Statement is never triggered within Chrono Program

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

### Abstract:

I wrote a short program dealing with the Chrono library in C++ for experimentation purposes. I want the CPU to count as high as it can within one second, display what it counted to, then repeat the process within an infinite loop.

### Current Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int counter()
{
    int num = 0;
    auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    while (true)
    {
        num++;
        auto currentTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        if (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(currentTime - startTime).count() == 1)
            return num;
    }
}

int main()
{
    while(true)
        std::cout << "You've counted to " << counter() << "in one second!";
    return 0;
}
```

### Problem:

The conditional statement in my program:

```
if (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(currentTime - startTime).count() == 1)
```

isn't being triggered because the casted value of currentTime - startTime never equals nor rises above one. This can be demonstrated by replacing the operator '==' with '<', which outputs an incorrect result, as opposed to outputting nothing at all. I don't understand why the condition isn't being met; if this program is gathering time from the system clock at one point, then repeatedly comparing it to the current time, shouldn't the integer value of the difference equal one at some point?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0322363cccf6b33) with Clang, GCC and VS. What compiler are you using?

Comment: That's odd; I'm using GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting a `cout` issue, not a `chrono` issue.  The problem is that you're printing with `cout` which doesn't flush if it doesn't feel like it.

`cerr` will flush on newline.  Change to `cerr` and add a `\n` and you'll get what you expect.

```
std::cerr << "You've counted to " << counter() << "in one second!\n";
```

Comment: Oddly enough, I didn't need to replace `cout` with `cerr`, I just needed to add `\n` (or `std::endl`) to the end of my line. Nonetheless, it works now, so thank you. That being said, why would something like this occur? Shouldn't the text print out anyways, regardless if it's on a new line or not?

Comment: @MichaelLilley:  `cout` is allowed to buffer output until its internal buffer is full, then flush.  This is for performance reasons.   Flushing is expensive.  `cerr` is required to flush on `\n`.  `endl` is shorthand for `\n + flush()`.